# Is it possible to combine or reduce these sql statements?

Tags: sql, plsql, group-by, where-clause

I'm not particularly familiar with SQL, but my team asked me to take a look at this series of sql statements and see if it is possible to reduce it down to just 1 or 2. I looked at it, and I don't believe so, but I don't quite have the experience or knowledge of the tricks of sql.

So all of the statements have pretty much the same format

```
select 
    id, count(*) 
from 
    table 
where 
    x_date between to_date(start_date) and to_date(end_date) 
group by 
    id
```

where x_date is the only thing that changes. (Start_date and end_date are just what I typed here to make it a bit more readable). There are 10 statements total, 7 of which are exactly this format.

Of the 3 different ones, one of them looks like this:

```
select 
    id, count(*) 
from 
    table 
where 
    x_date between to_date(start_date) and to_date(end_date) 
    and userid not like 'AUTOPEND' 
group by 
    id
```

and the other 2 look like this:

```
select 
    id, count(*) 
from 
    table 
where 
    x_date between to_date(start_date) and to. _date(end_date) 
group by 
    id, x_code
```

Where x_code differs between them.

They want to use this data for statistical analysis, but they insist on manually using a query and typing it in. The way I see it is that I can't really combine these statements because they are all grouping by the same field (except the last 2), so it all gets combined in the results, making the results useless for the analysis.

Am I thinking about it right, or is there some way to do like they asked? Can I make a 1 or 2 sql statements output more than 1 table each?

Oh, I almost forgot. I believe that this is Oracle PL/SQL using SQL developer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to get multiple aggregates with different grouping sets in a single query.  This is called a ROLLUP or a CUBE. There are a few ways to solve your specific problem, but the extended grouping functions are the right tool for the job.  Going forward, it will be more maintainable and faster.

http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/misc/rollup-cube-grouping-functions-and-grouping-sets.php

Answer (score 0):

Since the first and second example are grouping by the same thing you can use `CASE` statement nested in an aggregation function:

```
SELECT id, COUNT(*) ,
           SUM( CASE WHEN userid not like 'AUTOPEND' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS [NotAUTOPEND]
FROM table 
WHERE x_date between to_date(start_date) and to_date(end_date) 
GROUP BY id
```

Comment: But the results from the 7 structurally identical queries would still be summed together though, right?